# Why does countDistinct/n_distinct on SparkR column not work?

Tags: r, apache-spark, count, sparkr

I want to count distinct elements of a SparkR column (of a SparkR dataframe):

```
df$col1
1
2
2
5
6
5
```

distinct elements: 1,2,5,6

When I try [countDistinct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/R/countDistinct.html) on my SparkR Column, I only get this result:

```
> countDistinct(df$col1)
Column count(col1)
```

Do I have to use the agg function? I tried but failed because it doesn't seem to work on Columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And this is the expected result. SparkR column is not a data container. It is just a representation of logical operation in the execution plan. If you to get a result you have evaluate it in a specific context:

```
# 2.0.0+ syntax
df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(col1=c(1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 5)))

collect(select(df, countDistinct(df$col1)))
##   count(DISTINCT col1)                                        
## 1                    4
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought countDistinct would already result in the action, yet it was only the transformation.

Comment: Actually `countDistinct` is not even a transformation. Even if you call it on `df$col1` it is not bound to any specific data.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant to say that it is only a discription of what is going to happen with the data at the time of the action.

Comment: In a sense yes but it substantially different from you may know about RDD API. If you're looking for equivalents then `select(df, ...)` would be a transformations, `collect` an action, but `countDistinct(df$col1)` is just a function which will be evaluated with whatever data is passed to select.

Answer (score 0):

```
  > df <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,5,6)
   > df_uniq <- unique(df)
   > length(df_uniq)
    [1] 7
```

find out the unique values in the columns in your df

```
unique(df$col1)
length(unique(df$col1))
```

Hope you will get your answer.

Comment: Thank you, but I have a column in a distributed dataset and not a vector.

Comment: do you want to apply it on columns ??

Comment: No, I want to apply it on only one column in a distributed dataframe: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html